# How to upgrade one custom module from open erp 7.0 to ODOO 8.0?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, upgrade, openerp-7

I would like to update My Custom module which was already installed and written in OpenErp v7.0. But i want to migrate to ODOO v8.0. Can anybody please help me with this problem. what is the exact process to upgrade codes and all?

Thanks, Chandu

Comment: Did you try running the old module with fixed imports already?

Answer (score 0):

First you've got to fix the imports from version 7 to version 8
as an example

```
import osv
```

will be

```
import openerp.osv
```

in version 8

The models used in version 8 are almost the same as in version 7. So there's a big chance that you'll only have to fix the imports.

If the models you've used in version 7 don't exist anymore. you should search for the models that replaced it and rewrite the code to the new models.

Answer (score 0):

> Though this is not the correct platform to ask this kind of question
>   To get you started with NEW API code .. Here are some of the new concepts that you should start to look around on the web.

[1] **Record/Recordset and Model**

The new version 8.0 of OpenERP/Odoo introduce a new ORM API.

It intends to add a more coherent and concise syntax and provide a bi-directional compatibility.

The new API keeps its previous root design as Model and Record but now adds new concepts like Environment and Recordset.

[2] **Model**

A model is a representation of a business Object.

It is basically a class that define various class know-how and fields that are stored in database. All functions defined in a Model where previously callable directly by the Model.

This paradigm has changed as generally you should not access Model directly but a RecordSet

To instantiate a model you must inherit an openerp.model.Model:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _


class MyModel(models.Model):

    _name = 'a.model'  # Model identifer used for table name

    firstname = fields.Char(string="Firstname")
```

[3] **Modifing Environment**

If you need to modifiy your current context you may use the with_context() function.

```
self.env['res.partner'].with_context(tz=x).create(vals)
```

Be careful not to modify current RecordSet using this functionality:

```
self = self.env['res.partner'].with_context(tz=x).browse(self.ids)
```

It will modifiy the current Records in RecordSet after a rebrowse and will generate an incoherence between caches and RecordSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Openupgrade to migrate your database from openerp7 to odoo.
Download [Openupgrade](https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/blob/8.0/scripts/migrate.py) script and run it from terminal:

`python migrate.py --config=[your openerp.conf] --database=[your database] --run-migrations=8.0`

Comment: I have downloaded migrate.py then how can i proceed?? i didn't get u exactly what you are saying

Comment: python migrate.py --config=[openerp-server.conf ] --database=[transtech8] --run-migrations=8.0

Comment: then i got No user found on the system.... python migrate.py --config=[openerp-server.conf ] --database=[transtech8] --run-migrations=8.0

Comment: give database user and password in openerp-server.conf.

Comment: python migrate.py --config="/home/anipr/Documents/openerp-7.0/install/openerp-server.conf" --database="transtech" --run-migrations="8.0"

linking server/addons to /var/tmp/openupgrade/8.0/addons

getting git://github.com/OpenUpgrade/OpenUpgrade.git

sh: 1: git: not found

copying database transtech to transtech_migrated...

Copying the database using 'with template'

running migration for 8.0

sh: 1: /var/tmp/openupgrade/8.0/server/openerp-server: not found

I am getting this kind of error could you plz resolve??